# Table-valued function displaying only 1 result

Tags: sql-server

I've got this table valued function and I want it to display all records with the same "PeopleID". How can I do it? It's currently displaying only 1 of the possible results.

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.ufnGetContactInformation(@FuncID int)
RETURNS @retContactInformation TABLE 
(
    -- Columns returned by the function
    FuncID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    Full_Name nvarchar(75) NULL, 
    Phone nvarchar(100) NULL, 
    Email nvarchar(50) NULL, 
    City nvarchar(20) NULL
)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        @fullname nvarchar(75),
        @phonenumber nvarchar(100),
        @email nvarchar(50),
        @city nvarchar(20);

    -- > Get common contact information
    SELECT
            @fullname = p.Full_Name,
            @phonenumber = c.Phone, 
            @email = c.Email,
            @city = c.CityID
            FROM d_People p, d_Contacts c
            WHERE p.PeopleID=@FuncID;
    -- < Get common contact information
    IF @FuncID IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        INSERT @retContactInformation
        SELECT @FuncID, @fullname, @phonenumber, @email, @city;
    END;
    RETURN;
END;
GO
```

Comment: Why have you introduced a set of scalar variables in the middle when you could just `INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE`? That's what's collapsing your result set to one row.

Comment: (Also, because you're using the old-style comma join in your `FROM` clause, you've fallen into the common error of forgetting to specify your join conditions in the `WHERE` clause so your actual result set is joining *some* `People` rows with **every** `Contacts` row - you might want to consider switching to using `INNER JOIN` - it's only been a standard part of SQL for 25 years)

Comment: Okay, I've updated all my other selects also, thank you for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a proper `join` for your two tables, otherwise your query makes no sense. What you have now will give you one person `full_name`, but every contact `phone`, `email`, and `city`.

[Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

---

When you select into the scalar variables, you will only get one result in each variable. Inserting the variables after setting them to only hold one row will only ever yield at most one row.

You can simplify your function as an in-line table-valued function like so:

```
alter function dbo.ufngetcontactinformation(@funcid int)
returns table as return (
  select 
     funcid = p.peopleid
   , fullname = p.full_name
   , phonenumber = c.phone
   , email = c.email
   , city = c.cityid
  from d_people p, d_contacts c
  where p.peopleid = @funcid;
);
go
```

Reference

- [When is a SQL function not a function? "If it’s not inline, it’s rubbish." - Rob Farley](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2011/11/08/when-is-a-sql-function-not-a-function/)
- [Inline Scalar Functions - Itzik Ben-Gan](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/inline-scalar-functions)
- [Scalar functions, inlining, and performance: An entertaining title for a boring post - Adam Machanic](http://dataeducation.com/scalar-functions-inlining-and-performance-an-entertaining-title-for-a-boring-post/)
- [TSQL User-Defined Functions: Ten Questions You Were Too Shy To Ask - Robert Sheldon](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/tsql-user-defined-functions-ten-questions-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/)

---

If you have to have a multi-statement table valued function despite the perfomance hit:

```
alter function dbo.ufngetcontactinformation(@funcid int)
returns @retcontactinformation table 
(
    -- columns returned by the function
    funcid int primary key not null, 
    full_name nvarchar(75) null, 
    phone nvarchar(100) null, 
    email nvarchar(50) null, 
    city nvarchar(20) null
)
as 
begin
  insert @retcontactinformation
select 
    @funcid
  , p.full_name
  , c.phone
  , c.email
  , c.cityid
from d_people p, d_contacts c
where p.peopleid = @funcid;
return;
end;
go
```

Comment: Simplifying the function made it easier to understand when reading. Thank you, this helped me a lot!